# Encrypting guest VM ESXI 6.5 with Bitlocker

Tags: vmware-esxi, virtual-machines, encryption

Hi we're devs playing around with ESXI on some old R710s. For our dev enviromnment it will be fine. The R710 have a TPM. I tried encrypting the VM with Bitlocker but it couldn't see the TPM. I assume ESXI can't see it. I was thinking of perhaps Veracrypt. Our main requirements are:

- Encrypted Windows machines (although we could also be using Linux).
- My primary concern is ensuring if disks are disposed of, perhaps
  accidentally, nothing will be on them.
- Typing in password at boot-up isn't an issue for us as it's a dev
  environment.

So my questions are:

- Am I right in assuming ESXI can't see the TPM.
- Is Veracrypt viable in VM - I'm new to using it in a virtual
  environment so I'm unsure of potential issues in the longer term. I'm going to try it
  tonight on a test VM.
- It's ESXI v6.5 so there is some encryption support but we are
  currently using the free version and the tutorials looked fairly
  complicated and aimed at a more professional environment.

Any alternative suggestions are welcome. Cheers, Chris.

Comment: Why do you need to encrypt the VMs?

Comment: You can use BitLocker in the guest virtual machines without a TPM by following this procedure - https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/6229/how-to-use-bitlocker-on-drives-without-tpm/

Answer (score 2):

If you're on 6.5, why not just use the native vSphere VM Encryption?

https://blogs.vmware.com/vsphere/2016/10/whats-new-in-vsphere-6-5-security.html

> Encryption of virtual machines is something that’s been on-going for years. But, in case you hadn’t noticed, it just hasn’t “taken off” because every solution has a negative operational impact. With vSphere 6.5 we are addressing that head on.
>
> Encryption will be done in the hypervisor, “beneath” the virtual machine. As I/O comes out of the virtual disk controller in the VM it is immediately encrypted by a module in the kernel before being send to the kernel storage layer. Both VM Home files (VMX, snapshot, etc) and VMDK files are encrypted.

Comment: What I've read seemed to involve setting up a VCentre server to manage the keys and so on. This seems quite complicated - remembers we're devs and a bit new to this! And seems to mean the server can't be encrypted which may be fine in a enterprise environment but might be a little beyond us. Perhaps it's simpler than it looks. I was looking at this guy who seems quite good: https://www.vladan.fr/vmware-vsphere-6-5-vm-encryption-details/

Comment: Actually just looked at this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L_OvS0YXPiY but I'm not sure if we can do this will a single ESXI box. I'll try tomorrow and post if I have any luck.

Comment: I guess I didn't even know 6.5 had encryption.

Comment: 6.5 had encryption function. There are over the question how okay this encryption works. AFAIK this procedure harms IOPs hardly.

Comment: Because it requires a key management appliance which would cost far more than OP's host. And the only FOSS solution (PyKIMP) doesn't support persistent key storage so you lose them all if you restart the process.

Answer (score 1):

Of the main options we went for VeraCrypt

- Relying on keeping a key in a USB stick whether physical or some kind
  of virtual thing seemed to defeat the idea encyypting. What if the
  USB stick gets stolen etc.
- ESXI native encryption needs a server to hold the keys - see this
  post https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5-1ejlPGEcU, which seemed a
  little beyond us devs!
- Veracrypt is simple and just requires someone to enter the password
  on boot. For our scenario, which is hosting UAT servers etc to
  support our local development, this was an acceptable compromise.
  Unattended reboot, in our case, wasn't as issue.